# What does `~` mean in Haskell?

Tags: syntax, haskell, pattern-matching

I'm studying the `mtl` library and trying to do some MonadTransformers of my own. I was checking the `Control.Monad.State.StateT` declaration, and across all the code, I see this syntax:

```
execStateT :: (Monad m) => StateT s m a -> s -> m s
execStateT m s = do
  ~(_, s') <- runStateT m s
  return s'
```

What does this `~` operand mean?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is the notation for a lazy pattern in Haskell. I can't say that I'm familiar with it but [from here](http://www.haskell.org/tutorial/patterns.html):

> It is called a lazy pattern, and has
>   the form ~pat. Lazy patterns are
>   irrefutable: matching a value v
>   against ~pat always succeeds,
>   regardless of pat. Operationally
>   speaking, if an identifier in pat is
>   later "used" on the right-hand-side,
>   it will be bound to that portion of
>   the value that would result if v were
>   to successfully match pat, and ⊥
>   otherwise.

Also, [this section](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Laziness#When_does_it_make_sense_to_use_lazy_patterns.3F) may be useful.

Answer (score 9):

For a normal pattern match, the value that should be matched needs to be evaluated, so that it can be compared against the pattern.

`~` denotes a lazy pattern match: It is just assumed that the value will match the pattern. The match is then only done later, if the value of a matched variable is actually used.

Answer (score 4):

It's equivalent to

```
execStateT m s = do
  r <- runStateT m s
  return (snd r)
```

or

```
execStateT m s =
  runStateT m s >>= return . snd
```