# Why does this loops with 'data' but not 'newtype'?

Tags: haskell

Here is the code :

```
import Control.Applicative

-- newtype Parser a = Parser { runParser :: String -> [(a, String)] }
data Parser a = Parser { runParser :: String -> [(a, String)] }

instance Functor Parser where
  fmap f (Parser p) = Parser (\s -> [(f x, s') | (x, s') <- p s ] )

instance Applicative Parser where
  pure a = Parser (\s -> [(a, s)])
  Parser q <*> Parser p = Parser (\s -> [(f x, s'') | (f, s') <- q s, (x, s'') <- p s'])

instance Alternative Parser where
  empty = Parser (\s -> [])
  Parser q <|> Parser p = Parser (\s -> q s ++ p s)

item = Parser (\s -> case s of
                  (x:xs) -> [(x, xs)]
                  _ -> []
              )
```

With the current code, `runParser (some item) "abcd"` loops, but if Parser is declared as `newtype`, it works just fine.

Comment: What exactly are you asking? Do you have an example you could show of this?

Comment: There is almost no information in this question. We can't guess what's going on if you don't share more details. You should provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a great way of getting at one of [the difference between `data` and `newtype`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5889696/difference-between-data-and-newtype-in-haskell). The heart of the problem here is actually in the pattern matching of the `<|>` definition.

```
instance Alternative Parser where
  empty = Parser (\s -> [])
  Parser q <|> Parser p = Parser (\s -> q s ++ p s)
```

Remember that at runtime, a `newtype` becomes the same thing as the type it is wrapping. Then, when a `newtype` is pattern matched, GHC doesn't do anything - there is no constructor to evaluate to WNHF.

On the contrary, when a `data` is matched, seeing the pattern `Parser q` tells GHC it needs to evaluate that parser to WNHF. That is a problem, because `some` is an infinite fold of `<|>`. There are two ways to solve the problem with `data`:

- Don't have `Parser` patterns in `<|>`:

  ```
  instance Alternative Parser where
    empty = Parser (\s -> [])
    q <|> p = Parser (\s -> runParser q s ++ runParser p s)
  ```
- Use [lazy patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2263541/what-does-mean-in-haskell):

  ```
  instance Alternative Parser where
    empty = Parser (\s -> [])
    ~(Parser q) <|> ~(Parser p) = Parser (\s -> q s ++ p s)
  ```

Comment: The first strict pattern is fine, because `<|>` is left-biased. So this could be written `Parser q <|> ~(Parser p) = ...`. But of course the best solution in this case is just to use `newtype`!

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot. I still don't quite understand the relationship between a `data` being evaluated to a WNHF and the problem about `<|>` though.